# I want to display month and year in an iOS application. How do I switch the month?

Tags: ios, swift

The calendar moves to the next month but does not move back to previous month. What am I missing

The screen contains:

> 1. A collection view calendarCollectionView
> 2. A button previousMonth
> 3. A button nextMonth
> 4. A label monthYearLabel

The previousMonth and nextMonth buttons are connected to the IBAction btnLeftRight().

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
 {

@IBOutlet weak var previousMonth: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var nextMonth: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var monthYearLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var calendarCollectionView: UICollectionView!





//Initialize some variables:

var numOfDaysInMonth = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
var currentMonthIndex: Int = 0
var currentYear: Int = 0
var presentMonthIndex = 0
var presentYear = 0
var todaysDate = 0
var firstWeekDayOfMonth = 0





func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numOfDaysInMonth[currentMonthIndex-1] + firstWeekDayOfMonth - 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell
    //cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    if indexPath.item <= firstWeekDayOfMonth - 2 {
        cell.isHidden=true
    } else {
        let calcDate = indexPath.row-firstWeekDayOfMonth+2
        cell.isHidden=false
        cell.dateLabel.text="\(calcDate)"
        if calcDate < todaysDate && currentYear == presentYear && currentMonthIndex == presentMonthIndex {
            //Disable user interaction on past dates
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=false
            //Colour of the text in past date cells
            cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        } else {
            //Enable user interaction on upcoming dates
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
            //Colour of the text in upcoming date cells
            cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
        }
    }
    return cell
}





func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.width/7 - 8
    let height: CGFloat = 40
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 8.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 8.0
}


//Array that contains name of the days in a week:
var daysArr = ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"]
//Iteration for the properties of each day in a week:






override func viewDidLoad() {
    currentMonthIndex = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date()) - 1
    currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
    todaysDate = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date())
    firstWeekDayOfMonth=getFirstWeekDay()

    //for leap years, make february month of 29 days
    if currentMonthIndex == 2 && currentYear % 4 == 0 {
        numOfDaysInMonth[currentMonthIndex-1] = 29
    }

    presentMonthIndex=currentMonthIndex
    presentYear=currentYear


    monthYearLabel.text="\(monthsArr[currentMonthIndex]) \(currentYear)"



    previousMonth.isEnabled = false






    calendarCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "DateCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}


//Change the number of days in a month(next/previous):
@IBAction func btnLeftRightAction(sender: UIButton) {
    //When next month button is clicked:
    if sender == nextMonth {
        //Increment the index of the current month:
        currentMonthIndex += 1
        //Check if next month is January of the next year:
        if currentMonthIndex > 11 {
            //Reset the current month index:
            currentMonthIndex = 0
            //Increment the current year:
            currentYear += 1
        }
    }
        //When previous month button is clicked:
    else {
        //Decrement the index of the current month:
        currentMonthIndex -= 1
        //Check if previous month is December of the last year:
        if currentMonthIndex < 0 {
            //Reset the current month index:
            currentMonthIndex = 11
            //Decrement the current year:
            currentYear -= 1
        }
    }
    // Set label text for Month-Year:
    monthYearLabel.text="\(monthsArr[currentMonthIndex]) \(currentYear)"
    //Call didChangeMonth function:
    didChangeMonth(monthIndex: currentMonthIndex, year: currentYear)
}







func getFirstWeekDay() -> Int {
    let day = ("\(currentYear)-\(currentMonthIndex)-01".date?.firstDayOfTheMonth.weekday)!
    return day == 7 ? 1 : day
    //return day
}


func didChangeMonth(monthIndex: Int, year: Int) {
    currentMonthIndex=monthIndex+1
    currentYear = year

    //for leap year, make february month of 29 days
    if monthIndex == 1 {
        if currentYear % 4 == 0 {
            numOfDaysInMonth[monthIndex] = 29
        } else {
            numOfDaysInMonth[monthIndex] = 28
        }
    }
    //end

    firstWeekDayOfMonth=getFirstWeekDay()

    calendarCollectionView.reloadData()

    previousMonth.isEnabled = !(currentMonthIndex == presentMonthIndex && currentYear == presentYear)
}

















//Month and year name:

//The array that contains the name of the months:
var monthsArr = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]









}


//get first day of the month
extension Date {
var weekday: Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: self)
}
var firstDayOfTheMonth: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month], from: self))!
}
}


//get date from string
extension String {
static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter
}()

var date: Date? {
    return String.dateFormatter.date(from: self)
}
}
```

Comment: because all time you do currentMonthIndex -= 1 in IBAction, you do  currentMonthIndex=monthIndex+1 in didChangeMonth. So, the month dont change

Comment: I have some similar iin Objective C, the point is, you have to had on only one point where change the month var.

Comment: Thanks @ClaudioCastro. As pointed out in the answer, there are two mistakes.  1. In the didChangeMonth(monthIndex:year:) method,      currentMonthIndex = monthIndex.  2. In the getFirstWeekDay() function,      let day = ("\(currentYear)-\(currentMonthIndex+1)-01".date?.firstDayOfTheMonth.weekday)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sometimes assuming that the `currentMonthIndex` is zero-indexed, in other places you are assuming it is one-indexed. I've made some changes to your code to fix this. As @Claudio Castro mentioned, in your `didChangeMonth(monthIndex:year:)` method, you are setting `currentMonthIndex` to `monthIndex + 1`. This is the issue causing your previous button to stay in the same month (you first do -1, then +1, so nothing changes).

If you update your code to the below, it should work fine.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{

    @IBOutlet weak var previousMonth: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var nextMonth: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var monthYearLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var calendarCollectionView: UICollectionView!





    //Initialize some variables:

    var numOfDaysInMonth = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    var currentMonthIndex: Int = 0
    var currentYear: Int = 0
    var presentMonthIndex = 0
    var presentYear = 0
    var todaysDate = 0
    var firstWeekDayOfMonth = 0





    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numOfDaysInMonth[currentMonthIndex] + firstWeekDayOfMonth - 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell
        //cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
        if indexPath.item <= firstWeekDayOfMonth - 2 {
            cell.isHidden=true
        } else {
            let calcDate = indexPath.row-firstWeekDayOfMonth+2
            cell.isHidden=false
            cell.dateLabel.text="\(calcDate)"
            if calcDate < todaysDate && currentYear == presentYear && currentMonthIndex == presentMonthIndex {
                //Disable user interaction on past dates
                cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=false
                //Colour of the text in past date cells
                cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            } else {
                //Enable user interaction on upcoming dates
                cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
                //Colour of the text in upcoming date cells
                cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
            }
        }
        return cell
    }





    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = collectionView.frame.width/7 - 8
        let height: CGFloat = 40
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 8.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 8.0
    }


    //Array that contains name of the days in a week:
    var daysArr = ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"]
    //Iteration for the properties of each day in a week:






    override func viewDidLoad() {
        currentMonthIndex = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date()) - 1
        currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
        todaysDate = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date())
        firstWeekDayOfMonth=getFirstWeekDay()

        //for leap years, make february month of 29 days
        if currentMonthIndex == 2 && currentYear % 4 == 0 {
            numOfDaysInMonth[currentMonthIndex-1] = 29
        }

        presentMonthIndex=currentMonthIndex
        presentYear=currentYear


        monthYearLabel.text="\(monthsArr[currentMonthIndex]) \(currentYear)"



        previousMonth.isEnabled = false






        calendarCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "DateCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }


    //Change the number of days in a month(next/previous):
    @IBAction func btnLeftRightAction(sender: UIButton) {
        //When next month button is clicked:
        if sender == nextMonth {
            //Increment the index of the current month:
            currentMonthIndex += 1
            //Check if next month is January of the next year:
            if currentMonthIndex > 11 {
                //Reset the current month index:
                currentMonthIndex = 0
                //Increment the current year:
                currentYear += 1
            }
        }
            //When previous month button is clicked:
        else {
            //Decrement the index of the current month:
            currentMonthIndex -= 1
            //Check if previous month is December of the last year:
            if currentMonthIndex < 0 {
                //Reset the current month index:
                currentMonthIndex = 11
                //Decrement the current year:
                currentYear -= 1
            }
        }
        // Set label text for Month-Year:
        monthYearLabel.text="\(monthsArr[currentMonthIndex]) \(currentYear)"
        //Call didChangeMonth function:
        didChangeMonth(monthIndex: currentMonthIndex, year: currentYear)
    }







    func getFirstWeekDay() -> Int {
        let day = ("\(currentYear)-\(currentMonthIndex + 1)-01".date?.firstDayOfTheMonth.weekday)!
        return day == 7 ? 1 : day
        //return day
    }


    func didChangeMonth(monthIndex: Int, year: Int) {
        currentMonthIndex=monthIndex
        currentYear = year

        //for leap year, make february month of 29 days
        if monthIndex == 1 {
            if currentYear % 4 == 0 {
                numOfDaysInMonth[monthIndex] = 29
            } else {
                numOfDaysInMonth[monthIndex] = 28
            }
        }
        //end

        firstWeekDayOfMonth=getFirstWeekDay()

        calendarCollectionView.reloadData()

        previousMonth.isEnabled = !(currentMonthIndex == presentMonthIndex && currentYear == presentYear)
    }

















    //Month and year name:

    //The array that contains the name of the months:
    var monthsArr = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]









}


//get first day of the month
extension Date {
    var weekday: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: self)
    }
    var firstDayOfTheMonth: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month], from: self))!
    }
}


//get date from string
extension String {
    static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()

    var date: Date? {
        return String.dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. This works perfectly. The months change in the correct way. Before this solution, I changed currentMonthIndex = monthIndex in didChangeMonth() but that did not work. The app crashed when I changed the month to January of next year. Somehow I missed the +1 in getFirstWeekDay()....   let day = ("\(currentYear)-\(currentMonthIndex+1)-01".date?.firstDayOfTheMonth.weekday)!